# I got an error "Invalid content was found starting with element AuctionItems" for the xml file

Tags: xml, eclipse, jsp

I just supposed to develop a website based on the XSD schema, and I import the XML file to web-inf folder, I got an error that Invalid content was found starting with element `AuctionItems`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<AuctionItems> <!--this is where the error I got,its a complex type element-->
    <AuctionItem>
        <Title>MacBook Pro 2015</Title>
        <Category>Computers</Category>
        <Picture>http://www.w3schools.com/images/smiley.gif</Picture>
        <Description>Cool notebook</Description>
        <PostalAddress>
            <streetAddress>770 Eastern Parkway</streetAddress>
            <city>Sydney</city>
            <state>NSW</state>
            <country>Australia</country>
            <postalCode>2000</postalCode>
        </PostalAddress>
        <ReservePrice currency="AUD">1026.00</ReservePrice>
        <BiddingStartPrice currency="AUD">100.00</BiddingStartPrice>
        <BiddingIncrements>10</BiddingIncrements>
        <EndTime>2002-09-24-06:00</EndTime>
        <ID>faced800-d358-11e4-a715-0002a5d5c51b-26</ID>
    </AuctionItem>
    <AuctionItem>
        <Title>MacBook Pro 2008</Title>
        <Category>Computers</Category>
        <Picture>http://www.w3schools.com/images/smiley.gif</Picture>
        <Description>Old notebook</Description>
        <PostalAddress>
            <streetAddress>770 Eastern Parkway</streetAddress>
            <city>Sydney</city>
            <state>NSW</state>
            <country>Australia</country>
            <postalCode>2000</postalCode>
        </PostalAddress>
        <ReservePrice currency="AUD">613.00</ReservePrice>
        <BiddingStartPrice currency="AUD">100.00</BiddingStartPrice>
        <BiddingIncrements>10</BiddingIncrements>
        <EndTime>2002-09-24-06:00</EndTime>
        <ID>f3fefea6-d443-11e4-b9d6-1681e6b88ec1-26</ID>
    </AuctionItem>
</AuctionItems>
</web-app>
```

XSD file is below:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="AuctionItems">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="AuctionItem" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Title">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:minLength value="0"/>
                                    <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Category" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="Picture" type="xs:anyURI"/>
                        <xs:element name="Description">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:minLength value="0"/>
                                    <xs:maxLength value="1000"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="PostalAddress">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="streetAddress"/>
                                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="city"/>
                                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="state"/>
                                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="country"/>
                                    <xs:element type="xs:short" name="postalCode"/>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="ReservePrice">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                    <xs:extension base="xs:decimal">
                                        <xs:attribute name="currency" type="currencyType"/>
                                    </xs:extension>
                                </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="BiddingStartPrice">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                    <xs:extension base="xs:decimal">
                                        <xs:attribute name="currency" type="currencyType"/>
                                    </xs:extension>
                                </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="BiddingIncrements" type="xs:decimal"/>
                        <xs:element name="EndTime" type="xs:date"/>
                        <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:simpleType name="currencyType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="GBP"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="EUR"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="USD"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="AUD"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Can you post the error you have?

Comment: complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'AuctionItems'. One of '{"http://
 java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":description, ....
 encoding-mapping-list}' is expected.

Comment: and I tried to give XSD a name space, and put it in xml, still doesn't work